# routing algorithm different to Dijkstra-concept

Tags: algorithm, routes, navigation, dijkstra, a-star

what kind of routing algorithms exists that are different to different to Dijkstra-concept?

Dijkstra (and A*,D*, bellman forge etc.) use this concept:
Get the *best* Node from known Nodes, expand this and save the results to the known Nodes.

Are there any concepts that are fundamental different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) is fundamentally different. It uses dynamic programing instead of the Dijkstra greedy approach and works for graphs with negative weight edges.